# Which differences in javascript object creation syntax have I not understood? IE8 vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, highcharts, javascript-objects

I am working with Highcharts, to display data graphically. I've chosen this library specifically because of its compatibility with both IE8 and a newer version of Google Chrome, as it renders the charts in VML or SVG, depending on supportability.

HighCharts can be created by defining a properties-object, which is passed as a parameter. This is working like a charm in Chrome, but I'm having trouble in IE8 (is there an echo in here?)

I suspect that the error is different syntax support for the two browsers, when defining an object in javascript. The two questions below are the closest thing I have come to finding any info, but they didn't address my actual problem.

[What are the most likely causes of Javascript errors in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359895/what-are-the-most-likely-causes-of-javascript-errors-in-ie8?rq=1)

[IE8 errors when defining a Javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323586/ie8-errors-when-defining-a-javascript-object)

My code for defining the properties object is stated below. My error is always in the first line of this snippet. However, I cannot find any errors in that line, so I think it has to be somewhere else, and only refer to it's "root". `entry` is an object with a few parameters, to populate the chart with titles and similar:

```
    var chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: "piecontainer"+index,
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: entry.title + '<br/><br/>' + entry.path + '<br/><br/>Total: ' + Object.keys(entry.testMap).length,
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 50
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b> {point.y} ({point.percentage:.1f}%)</b>'
        },     

        legend: {
            width: 415,
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            labelFormatter: function() {
                return '<span>' + this.name + ': ' + this.y + '<t/></span>';
            }, 
            itemDistance: 20
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                size: '100%',
                animation: false,
                 dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false                              
                    },
                    showInLegend: true,
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Test Cases',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [
                ['Passed',  1],
                ['Not Completed', 1],
                ['Failed', 1],
                ['No Run', 1],
                ['N/A', 1], 
                ['Blocked', 1],
                ['Incorrect Database Value', 1]
            ]
        }]
    };
```

**EDIT:**
As I can tell by this post: [Strange behavior Highcharts pie chart in document mode IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21602643/strange-behavior-highcharts-pie-chart-in-document-mode-ie8?rq=1), the main structure of my object notation is correct. There has to be a single line or two in the middle, that are causing the problems.

Comment: Can you add the actual error message into your question?

Comment: Just eyeing this, IE8 isn't ES5 compliant, so `Object.keys()` isn't available (_unless you're pulling in the es5-shim.js_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` is not supported in IE8. It is an ES5 specification, which is only supported from IE9 and above. You'll need a different way of getting at that information.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)...

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much. I suppose I might be able to extract line by line and check supportability, but I am very grateful for this help. Way faster for me. I will find another way to get the data. Guaranteed ;)

Comment: I'll acccept the answer in five minutes.

Comment: @KjetilNordin Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6700/726766) for more on how to get an object's length.

Comment: This is the reason I love SO :)

Comment: Score. It works. And in my opinion, the code is now also easier to read. Thanks a lot.